# OpenLayers - Video layer

Tags: html5-video, openlayers

I would like to present video (using a `<video></video>` element) over an OpenLayers map (currently using OL4)

I know that an Overlay can help me present the video on the map, but if I want to add layers over it, the overlay is on top of those layers..

Is there currently a way (in any OL version) to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, by using a `postcompose` hook. @tschaub has created an example a long time ago. See http://tschaub.net/ol3-video/examples/video.html. I have created a CodePan from it which uses the latest OpenLayers version. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWQqzj.

The `postcompose` hook looks like this:

```
layer.on('postcompose', function(event) {

  var frameState = event.frameState;
  var resolution = frameState.viewState.resolution;
  var origin = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(topLeft);

  var context = event.context;
  context.save();

  context.scale(frameState.pixelRatio, frameState.pixelRatio);
  context.translate(origin[0], origin[1]);
  context.rotate(rotation);
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, dx / resolution, height / resolution);

  context.restore();
});
```

`rotation` is taken from the video metadata. `topLeft`, `dx` and `height` are calculated from the video's extent.

To loop through the frames of the video, `render` needs to be called on the map in an interval:

```
setInterval(function() {
  map.render();
}, 1000 / 30);
```

Comment: is it possible to do so without an interval (i.e. is there an event for a frame change)? maybe in OL4?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: all references point to broken content.  Is this still applicable, or is there a better way today?